# Angular binding to attribute evaluates value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In directive code I have:

```
 scope:{
        'rendered':'=',
        'x':'='
      },
        restrict:'A',
        link:function (scope, element) {
            var x = scope.x
      ...
```

in HTML I have

```
 <div my-directive x='02/06'></div>
```

But in Link function var x = 0.333. How to prevent this evaluation? I need to get my '02/06'.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Escape it with quotes x="'02/06'"

Comment: Or if `x` will always be a literal value change the `scope` property `x` to a `@`.

Comment: It is hard to do b/c I get HTML in :var html =  "<div>Olala<div reportslisting-tooltip rendered='false' x='" + obj.x + "'></div></div>";

Comment: Davin - not clear what you mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `@` instead of `=` for `x`:

```
 scope:{
    'rendered':'=',
    'x':'@'
  }
  ...
```

so that the `x` attribute will be treated as a string literal instead of being interpreted.